# rails print style color in link_to

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to also now add background color to my link based on "bin.color" however it's not working and I can't find it in my app how I did it. So far I've got;

```
<%= link_to bin.label_name, linkbin_url(:id => bin.id), :class => "link", :style => bin.color %>
```

and I've tried the above which prints it out, but adding background like so, breaks it;

```
<%= link_to bin.label_name, linkbin_url(:id => bin.id), :class => "link", :style => background-color:bin.color %>
```

or even

```
<%= link_to bin.label_name, linkbin_url(:id => bin.id), :class => "link", :style => 'background-color: bin.color !important' %>
```

none seem not to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to interpolate the `bin.color`:

```
<%= link_to bin.label_name, linkbin_url(:id => bin.id), :class => "link", :style => "background-color: #{bin.color} !important"
```

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.  If this completely answers your question, please check the green checkmark next to this answer to close your question.